# MPI Task Scheduling

Tags: scheduled-tasks, mpi

I want to develop a task scheduler using MPI where there is a single master processor and there are worker/client processors. Each worker has all the data it needs to compute, but gets the index to work on from the master. After the computation the worker returns some data to the master. The problem is that some processes will be fast and some will be slow. 
If I run a loop so that at each iteration the master sends and receives (blocking/non-blocking) data then it can't proceed to next step till it has received data from the current worker from the previous index assigned to it. The bottom line is if a worker takes too long to compute then it becomes the limiting factor and the master can't move on to assign an index to the next worker even if non-blocking techniques are used. Is it possible to skip assigning to a worker and move on to next.

I'm beginning to think that MPI might not be the paradigm to do this. Would python be a nice platform to do task scheduling?

Comment: LAM/MPI provides a [detailed example](http://www.lam-mpi.org/tutorials/one-step/ezstart.php) of what you'd like to implement. Note that the "master/slave" terminology is a bit outdated and is now called "manager/worker" for the sake of political correctness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is absolutely possible using `MPI_Irecv()` and `MPI_Test()`. All the master process needs to do is post a non-blocking receive for each worker process, then in a loop test each one for incoming data. If a process is done, send it a new index, post a new non-blocking receive for it, and continue.

Comment: Yikes! Now that was straightforward. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One MPI_IRecv for each process is one solution.  This has the downside of needing to cancel unmatched MPI_IRecv when the work is complete.

MPI_ANY_SOURCE is an alternate path.  This will allow the manager process to have a single MPI_IRecv outstanding at any given time, and the "next" process to MPI_Send will be matched with MPI_ANY_SOURCE.  This has the downside of several ranks blocking in MPI_Send when there is no additional work to be done.  Some kind of "nothing more to do" signal needs to be worked out, so the ranks can do a clean exit.