# MPI Dynamic Receive

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, event-listener

I am new to MPI and I am developing a program that lists the divisors of a number. The algorithm is simple. I split the numbers from 2 to the square root of the number in threads and give them to the other processes. Then I take the results and merge them in one. A problem I have is that if I go over a big number range, it would take time for some of the nodes to process that, while others would do it faster. Then I need to process the responses of the faster ones and to give them new tasks.

In brief, I need something like a receive listener. Can you tell me such thing, or give a place from where I can read about it?

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible by blocking and non-blocking receives. This is better explained in other posts on stackoverflow like [MPI Task Scheduling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180624/mpi-task-scheduling?rq=1) and [Dynamic pool of workers with MPI for large array C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015291/dynamic-pool-of-workers-with-mpi-for-large-array-c)
. I think both the questions wanted something similar to what you are looking for. Hope this helps you look in the right direction.