# MPI dynamically allocate tasks

Tags: c++, mpi

I have a C++ MPI program that runs on Windows HPC cluster (12 nodes, 24 cores per node).

- The logic of the program is really simple:

  1. there is a pool of tasks
  2. At the start, the program divides the tasks equally to each MPI process
  3. Each MPI process execute their tasks
  4. After everything is finished, using MPI reduce to gather the results to the root process.

There is one problem. Each task can have drastically different execution time and there is no way that I can tell that in advance. Equally distributing the task will results a lot of processes waiting idle. This wastes a lot of computer resources and make the total execution time longer.

I am thinking of one solution that might work.

- The process is like this.

  1. The task pool is divided into small parcels (like 10 tasks a parcel)
  2. Each MPI process take a parcel at a time when it is idle (have not received a parcel, or finished the previous parcel)
  3. The step 2 is continued until the task pool is exhausted
  4. Using MPI reduce to gather all the results to root process

As far as I understand, this scheme need a universal counter across nodes/process (to avoid different MPI process execute the same parcel) and changing it need some lock/sync mechanism. It certainly has its overhead but with proper tuning, I think it can help to improve the performance.

I am not quite familiar with MPI and have some implementation issues. I can think of two ways to implement this universal counter

1. Using MPI I/O technique, write this counter in file, when a parcel is took, increase this counter (will certainly need file lock mechanism)
2. Using MPI one side communication/shared memory. Put this counter in the shared memory and increase it when a parcel is taken. (will certainly need a sync mechanism)

Unfortunately, I am not familiar with either technique and want to explore the possibility, implementation, or possible drawbacks of the two above methods. A sample code would be greatly appreciated.

If you have other ways to solve the problem or suggestions, that will also be great. Thanks.

Follow-ups:

Thanks for all the useful suggestions. I am implemented a test program following the scheme of using process 0 as the task distributor.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>

using namespace std;

void doTask(int rank, int i){
    cout<<rank<<" got task "<<i<<endl;
}

int main ()
{
    int numTasks = 5000;
    int parcelSize = 100;

    int numParcels = (numTasks/parcelSize) + (numTasks%parcelSize==0?0:1);

    //cout<<numParcels<<endl;

    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    int rank, nproc;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nproc);

    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Request request;

    int ready = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int maxParcelNow = 0;

    if(rank == 0){
        for(i = 0; i <numParcels; i++){
            MPI_Recv(&ready, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            //cout<<i<<"Yes"<<endl;
            MPI_Send(&i, 1, MPI_INT, status.MPI_SOURCE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            //cout<<i<<"No"<<endl;
        }
        maxParcelNow = i;
        cout<<maxParcelNow<<" "<<numParcels<<endl;
    }else{
        int counter = 0;
        while(true){
            if(maxParcelNow == numParcels) {
                cout<<"Yes exiting"<<endl;
                break;
            }
            //if(maxParcelNow == numParcels - 1) break;
            ready = 1;
            MPI_Send(&ready, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            //cout<<rank<<"send"<<endl;
            MPI_Recv(&i, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            //cout<<rank<<"recv"<<endl;
            doTask(rank, i);
        }
    }

    MPI_Bcast(&maxParcelNow, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);    

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

It does not work and it never stops. Any suggestions on how to make it work? Does this code reflect the idea right or am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: Do you absolutely need to gather the results of a given task after its completion, or you can defer that to a later time? Depending on your architecture, you may consider having a single MPI process whose role is to dispatch the tasks and gather the results.

Comment: I'd second what @AlexG has already suggested, that is having a master process take care of distributing tasks too, and gathering results from, the worker tasks.  Perhaps start your further studies here ...   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180624/mpi-task-scheduling

Comment: @AlexG The time does not matter that much as long as in the end, the root process get all the results from all other processes. A single process to dispatch task is actually a good idea. I have to look at it more closely. By the way, do you have some really concerns about using MPI I/O or one side communication? I am quite new here so I may not aware some big drawbacks you guys know. Thanks.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Really appreciate you give a sample code here.

Comment: @user11594134 You would have to see for yourself with benchmarks, but if the communication time is small compared to the time it takes to solve each task, then you're good to go. Point-to-point communication isn't that bad.

Comment: the described MPI/IO technique is both inefficient and ugly. You'd rather implement a master/slave algo first, and only if you cannot afford wasting one MPI task, move to the one sided communication (atomic operation should be enough). I do not know how the master process will use the gathered data, and you might consider having each MPI tasks write its result in its own file, or even in a shared file with MPI/IO and get rid of the gather.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, I tried to implemented according to the material you refers (see in the edited post), it never stops. Do you mind taking a look at it. Thanks

Comment: @AlexG I tried to implement a single MPI process which dispatch the job (see the sample code in the edited post), but it never stops. Could you take a look at it? Thanks

Comment: @user11594134 I'm a bit rusty, but it feels like process0 should send 1 message to each other process before waiting on any Recv. Your other processes should be on 'Recv' right from the start. Whenever a process completes its task, it should send the result back to process0. Process0 will issue another task to that process if there are any remaining, and so on until it's completed.
Your current implementation is flawed, you will wait on each process to complete its task 1 at a time, so no parallelism involved. Also, don't bother trying to count remaining work on other processes. Let p0 do it.

Comment: @AlexG the confusing part for me is how the slave processes stops. Once the the task are exhausted, how does the slave process know this and stops? The Bcast I use obvious does not work. But if they do not know when to stop, the program will never ends

Comment: @user11594134 Whenever process0 receives the result of a task, you can have it send back a message that has a special 'TAG' your other processes will know of, or an empty message. Look at the possibilies of send/recv and build on it.

Comment: @AlexG this is really useful. One thing I am still confusing is that if you put recv right from the start, how does to the root process tell which process to send to? As far as I know, the MPI send does not have an option to send to any process. If you let the root process assign as a round-robin way, this is not really dynamic allocating tasks. I must still misunderstanding something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Converting my comments into an answer...]

Given `n` processes, you can have your first process `p0` dispatch tasks for the other `n - 1` processes. First, it will do point-to-point communication to the other `n - 1` processes so that everyone has work to do, and then it will block on a `Recv`. When any given process completes, say `p3`, it will send its result back to `p0`. At this point, `p0` will send another message to `p3` with one of two things:

1) Another task

or

2) Some kind of termination signal if there are no tasks remaining. (Using the 'tag' of the message is one easy way.)

Obviously, `p0` will loop over that logic until there is no task left, in which case it will call `MPI_Finalize` too.

Unlike what you thought in your comments, this isn't round-robin. It first gives a job to every process, or worker, and then gives back another job whenever one completes...